# How to customize Ant.design styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

Who knows how to customize Ant.design styles in proper way?

For example, I want to change the default backgroundColor and height of Header section:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Layout } from 'antd';
const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout;

export default class Login extends Component {

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <Header style={{backgroundColor: '#555555', height: '5vh'}}>header</Header>
                <Layout>
                    <Content>main content</Content>
                </Layout>
                <Footer>footer</Footer>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Is it ok, or there is a better way to customize styles?
Because I have not found some component's attributes or smth. like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Antd has externized most of their styling variable in LESS variables

as you can see in

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less

To be able to overwrite those variables you need to use `modifyVar` function from LESS

you can find more about theming [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme)

So to your specific question, `@layout-header-background` does the job

Comment: With the update of antd to version 5 the list of less variables is no longer available using the link above. Github will report the page is not found. To still access the antd version 4 list of less variables use the following [link](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/4.24.3/components/style/themes/default.less)

Answer (score 14):

**This is how i customized the default antd styles in a particular component**

**In scss or less**

```
.booking_information_table {
    :global {
        .ant-table-thead > tr > th,
        .ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
            padding: 0 0 !important;
            background-color: unset;
            border: none;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
        }
 }
}
```

**In js file**

*after the import statement*

> import styles from './component.module.less'

**In return**

```
<Table
   dataSource={bookingInformationDataSource}
   columns={bookingInformationColumns}
   pagination={false}
   className={styles.booking_information_table}
 />
```

Comment: I have a problem using less modules, how did you configure them, I have errors of css in js, works fine with scss modules....

Answer (score 8):

My personal approach (I'm working with dva-cli though):

Every time I need to override the CSS, I use a CSS file located in the same folder and import it such as:

**your-component.js**:

```
import styles from './your-stylesheet.css';
...
< AntdComponent className= {styles.thestyle} />
```

**your-stylesheet.css**:

```
.thestyle {
  background-color: '#555555';
}
```

Comment: doing the same way, but I would like to have something like <Button bgColor="#dedede" width="20" height="10" ... />

Comment: inline style then: I would go :
```<Button style={{backgroundColor:"#dedede", width:20, height:10}}/>```

Answer (score 3):

In the less file(like a CSS) you can handle customize styles. For
example in your case

```
.ant-layout-header{ 
      height: 100vh;
      background-color:#f50;
}
```

If you use Ant card

```
.ant-card-head{color:#j14}
```

I hope you can understand now

Comment: yes, I see,  but how can I make top and bottom borders of that row which describes names of columns in a table?

Comment: I tried same thing by overriding the class, but no idea why it is not working. I am using less.

Answer (score 3):

The above mentioned approaches work for simple components like `Header` but don't always work for complex components like `Menu`, `Tabs`, `Collapse`, `Select`, and others, due to styles nesting priority. At work we use the approach described by **jayanes** but we go deeper into nested Ant Design classes. Let me explain it in the following example: when you import `Tabs` from "antd", you have only 2 tags to override styles for: `Tabs` and `TabPane`.

```
<div className={styles.tabsContainer}>
    <Tabs className={styles.tabs}>
        <TabPane className={styles.tabPane}>
            Tab 1 Title
        </TabPane>
    </Tabs>
</div>
```

But this antd component has a very complex structure. You can verify in dev tools: it has `.ant-tabs-bar`, `.ant-tabs-nav-container`, `.ant-tabs-tab-prev`, `.ant-tabs-tab-next`, `.ant-tabs-nav-wrap`, `.ant-tabs-nav-scroll`, `.ant-tabs-tab-active`, `.ant-tabs-ink-bar` and others.
The way to go is: **in your less file nest the `.ant-...` classes inside your own parent component's `className`** (in order to avoid overriding all the antd classes in the whole app after code compilation). Write there your own css properties, for example:

```
.tabsContainer {
    .ant-tabs-tab-active {
        background: #fff266;
        color: #31365c;
        &:hover {
            color: darken(#31365c, 5%);
        }
    }
    .ant-tabs-ink-bar {
        background: #fff266;
    }
}
```

If you still need more detailed explanation, please refer to the video I posted on YouTube on how to customize Ant Design components - tabs.

Comment: Hello Tania, where's the youtube link? Is this the same approach as makeStyles in MUI? I don't like the approach of modifying via less.

Comment: @duduwe my video on YouTube is "Ant Design library with React: customize components - tabs".

Comment: In my case, it is working for any nesting level. I'm just using plain CSS modules.

Answer (score 2):

Customizing Antd theme Colors can be a hassle thus, I created a package that allows you to change them easily with post CSS you can even change them to CSS variables and change them in runtime.
For more info https://www.npmjs.com/package/ant-post-css-theme

Answer (score 1):

Override the component style

Because of the special needs of the project, we often meet the need to cover the component style, here is a simple example.

[Override the component style](https://pro.ant.design/docs/style#Override-the-component-style)