# Setting width of Sider form antd via css

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

`Sider` component of Ant Design provides property `width` for setting width in js/JSX. However this width overrides any width specified in css via `ant-layout-sider` selector. Hence, I was wondering how can I specify width within css instead of js? I know about the `!important` rule in css, but I try to avoid it, hence I was wondering if there are alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using `!important`, it was original created as an override.

back in the 19-something, browsers each had their own stylesheets and web authors had this feature for css created, meaning that any attribute with `!important` would override the browser existing css code, moving on to 2019, it is still a common and acceptable practice.

on another note.

why don't you try using SASS instead of CSS, it is more dynamic and has a lot more options, you can mix and match css and sass files together.

### refs:

- [Ant Design Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620712/how-to-customize-ant-design-styles)
- [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: I am using sass. But what does relevance does it have with the question? Sider overrides both css/sass/etc...

Comment: @arslancharyev31 have a look at [Ant Design Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620712/how-to-customize-ant-design-styles)

Comment: Ok, so if I unnderstood correctly, without it is only possible via LESS, not CSS/SASS?