# How to change the fontSize in an Antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, size, antd, font-size

I tried to change the `fontSize`, but it did not take effect:

```
<Table
  style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: '100%', fontSize: '10px'}}
  dataSource={data.dataSource}
  columns={columns}
  size='small'
  bordered
  pagination={false}
/>
```

Also my table doesn't fit in the block. Only 3 columns are displayed and the rest disappear. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- your-stylesheet.scss:

  .ant-table table {
  font-size: 10px; }

Comment: thank you, it work. Please, can you help me how set width for columnt. I try : `.ant-table col { width: 50px;}` But it not work. My table is currently outside the block boundary of the Card

Comment: You can see the answer here :
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14291

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61832264/7213408) you can use **sass** or **less**.

```
    .booking_information_table {
        :global {
            .ant-table-thead > tr > th,
            .ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
                fontSize: '10px';
            }
    }
```

Secondly You can use the [scroll](https://ant.design/components/table/#scroll) property of Table and remove **overflow: hidden**