# Emotion style overruled by antd default style

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, antd, emotion

I have a Gatsby project and created a component as such:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/core'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import React from 'react'

import { AntDesignOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
import { Layout, Typography } from 'antd'
const AntHeader = Layout.Header
const { Title } = Typography

type Props = {
  siteTitle: string
}

const Header: React.FC<Props> = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <AntHeader>
    <div>
      <h1>
        <Link to="/" css={LinkStyle}>
          <AntDesignOutlined />
          {` `}
          {siteTitle}
        </Link>
      </h1>
      <TitleStyled>Title</TitleStyled>
    </div>
  </AntHeader>
)

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

const TitleStyled = styled(Title)`
  color: red;
`

const LinkStyle = css`
  color: #fff;
`

export default Header
```

And the style rules result in the TitleStyle being overwritten as in this example:
[image]

I have demoed this on the following Gatsby starter: https://github.com/yusugomori/gatsby-starter-antd-typescript-emotion

I am at a loss at what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with React, Gatsby, Ant Design, or Emotion, it's just CSS specificity. The selector `el.foo` has a higher specificity than just `.foo`, therefore its styles will take precedence. See [How are the points in CSS specificity calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/how-are-the-points-in-css-specificity-calculated) for more detail.

You might also find the [techniques for overriding styles outlined in the Ant documentation](https://pro.ant.design/docs/style#Override-the-component-style) useful. Additionally, there are a handful of alternate approaches here: [How to customize Ant.design styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620712/how-to-customize-ant-design-styles)

Comment: @coreward This is a great response, I feel like a simpleton based on the answer. I guess the follow up question is more about the implementation details of the `<Title />`. Would you not expect a component to be able to implement custom styles without having to update the less settings? The `<Button />` doesn't have this constraint if I want to update its color.